# Disable VM's triggers when hypervisor failed in Zabbix

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I've got Zabbix Server 4.4 and I'm newabe in custom coniguration of this. Mostly I wanna to reduce mail notyfication. I create groups of hosts which name is hypervisor hostname, but hypervisor host isn't inside. So I'm looking of way to off all triggers in host group when hypervisor failed.
It's even possible in zabbix?

Comment: This is vague, you should be more specific. Which kind of hypevisor? Which template are you using? For instance you can monitor Vmware through the VCSA using the official template (vcsa-hypervisor-vm discovery) and also the VMs through the agent... it depends!

Comment: On HV and VM's i use templates with zabbix agent. Hypervisors is Windows Server 2016, VM's it's mostly Debian/Ubuntu

Comment: If your hypervisor offers HA, you don't need this. VMs will just restart on a different Host, and you will not have a ton of "host down" notifications, just a ton of "host rebooted" notifications. And you can filter those off in the action. If your hypervisor does not offer HA... wtf?

Comment: Critical VM's have replication, but I don't have common storage to full failover.